# Pandas return empty dataframe when trying to scrape table

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to get the transfer history of the top 500 most valuable players on [Transfermarkt](https://www.transfermarkt.com/spieler-statistik/wertvollstespieler/marktwertetop). I've managed (with some help) to loop through each players profile and scraped image and name. Now I want the transfer history, which can be found in a table on each players profile: [Player Profile](https://www.transfermarkt.com/kylian-mbappe/profil/spieler/342229) [image]

I want to save the table in a dataframe, using Pandas and then write it to a CSV, with Season, Date etc as headers. For Monaco and PSG, for example, I just want the names of the clubs, not pictures or Nationality. But right now, all I get is this:

```
Empty DataFrame
Columns: []
Index: []
```

Expected output:

```
Season         Date    Left Joined       MV      Fee
0  18/19  Jul 1, 2018  Monaco    PSG  120.00m  145.00m
```

I've viewed the source and inspected the page, but can't find anything that helps me, apart from that the tbody and tr. But the way I'm doing it I want to precise that table, since there are several others.

This is my code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv
import pandas as pd

site = "https://www.transfermarkt.com/spieler-statistik/wertvollstespieler/marktwertetop?ajax=yw1&page={}"

headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:74.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/74.0'
}

result = []

def main(url):
    with requests.Session() as req:
        result = []
        for item in range(1, 21):
            print(f"Collecting Links From Page# {item}")
            r = req.get(url.format(item), headers=headers)
            soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')

            tr = soup.find_all("tbody")[1].find_all("tr", recursive=False)

            result.extend([
                { 
                    "Season": t[1].text.strip()

                }
                for t in (t.find_all(recursive=False) for t in tr)
            ])

df = pd.DataFrame(result)

print(df)
```

Comment: show us expected output.

Comment: I've added a expected output!

Comment: so you want the first row of that table ?

Comment: No, sorry! I want all rows. I just showed an example.

Comment: In order to get the information from the table that you have shown in the image above, you have to go one layer deep. With your current attempt you are still in the landing page @Zakan.

Comment: @SIM I thought that the code I'm using right now I'm entering the players profiles, but that is not the case, right? (I've received help with it) Thanks Sim

Comment: @Zakan the code which I wrote for you before, was working on the landing page. but the table which you targeting is within each player link. check below answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

site = "https://www.transfermarkt.com/spieler-statistik/wertvollstespieler/marktwertetop?ajax=yw1&page={}"

headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:74.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/74.0'
}


def main(url):
    with requests.Session() as req:
        links = []
        names = []

        for item in range(1, 21):
            print(f"Collecting Links From Page# {item}")
            r = req.get(url.format(item), headers=headers)
            soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')
            urls = [f"{url[:29]}{item.get('href')}" for item in soup.findAll(
                "a", class_="spielprofil_tooltip")]
            ns = [item.text for item in soup.findAll(
                "a", class_="spielprofil_tooltip")][:-5]
            links.extend(urls)
            names.extend(ns)
    return links, names


def parser():
    links, names = main(site)
    for link, name in zip(links, names):
        with requests.Session() as req:
            r = req.get(link, headers=headers)
            df = pd.read_html(r.content)[1]
            df.loc[-1] = name
            df.index = df.index + 1
            df.sort_index(inplace=True)
            print(df)


parser()
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! If I wanted to add player name to each table as well, to connect each table to each player, how would I do that?

Comment: @Zakan Kindly please include your points from the time you created the question. that's not the way how `Stackoverflow` community follows. you have to limit your question to specific problem, but with that way, you are just moving from issue to issue without taken time to show any self effort taken by you as a `programmer` to solve the issue !

Comment: My bad! Sorry, but sometimes I realize the problem after I've created the question. I'll try to manage by my self.